# Share View between Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In android I would create a single `layout` and then use it with `include` in another layout xml file. Like this I can share single layout with multiple `activity`. Now in iOS XCode I want this approach to share single view created as `.xib` into multiple `storyboards`. I can see a `View Controller` but I don't know how to `include` view .xib under that `View Controller`. Any idea?

Comment: you may need to use Container view

Comment: @ArslanAsim How? I can add `Container View` to the story board but how to include that .xib `View` in it?

Comment: you are not using storyboard entirely ??

Comment: I am using Storyboard but there is one view which is used with multiple storyboards.

Comment: if solution work, please accept :)

Answer (score 1):

According to your Comment, you need to add that .xib view programmatically on your desired controller
e.g.

```
[ViewInWhichYouWantToAdd addSubview:xibController.view]
```

Comment: Not sure how to use that... But I have found this step by step tutorial *Custom UIView from Xib file in Xcode 5 for Reusable Components* at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP7YvdlnHfA